# MYSQL Match string in column

Tags: mysql

I have a text inside a column and I want to make a search within this text but with only some words, for example:

> "gender:male,eye_color:blue,province:12"

How can I perform a query to match just "gender:male,province:12" in this text?

Thanks in advance

Comment: there are 3 fields is your colmn name

Comment: select * from tablename where gender='male' AND province='12';

Comment: @DarjiJigar column name? I'm talking about the content of a column, I don't specify a column name in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean this or not, just try it, I don't even know it works for your demand;)

```
select * from @table where @column like '%gender:male,%province:12%'
```